# What the line #!/usr/bin/python does?

Tags: python, programming

Im learning python but I dont understand what this line does? or how many options there is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is called a **shebang** and it tells the kernel which interpreter to use on the script.

For example, if a script is named with the path `path/to/script`, and it starts with the line `#!/bin/sh`, then the program loader is instructed to run the program `/bin/sh`, passing `path/to/script` as the first argument.

In your instance, the kernel will use whatever `/usr/bin/python` points to (I think it is by default `python3.6`).

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` should be Python 2.7. This is per [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), which says the command `python` should be Python 2.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for this :D " end users should be aware that python refers to python3 on at least *Arch Linux*" I failed to read past python3 when I was searching around for the default